# How fast would 2ft tall people process alcohol?

Tags: biology, earth-like, biochemistry, races, alcoholic-beverages

I have a world both of normal humans and a fantasy race that are basically 2ft tall, with large heads and torsos and stubby legs if that's important. They typically weigh about the same as a housecat.

I already assume that in order to get one of these smaller people drunk, you'd give them proportionally less alcohol, but how long would they stay drunk for compared to normal humans? Would it be shorter because of them drinking less of it, or longer because of their smaller livers, or something else? Would they also experience similar hangovers to a typical human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a biologist, Baruch Brody who did the research related to body-mass and metabolism. The famous "Elephant to Mouse Curve" (I'd not heard of it, and yes, I know, it's not a curve) shows the relative mass/metabolism of various animals:

[image: Straight-line graph.]

<sup>Brody's Famous curve, cribbed from [researchgate.com](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mouse-to-elephant-curve-2_fig2_253328797) 2022 fair-usage.</sup>

It shows that a 90Kg person metabolises at a base-rate of approx. 90j per second. A 2 kilogram cat at perhaps 9j per second. If this translates to the action of liver-enzymes breaking down alcohol, then cat-sized people recover (break-down booze) 4.5 times faster than people.

In practice, they'd drink 1/45th the amount to get drunk, get sober in less than a quarter of the time and suffer from the chemical effects of hangover (normally ketones giving you a headache) for a quarter of the time, and assuming they rehydrate appropriately, be up and about all bright-eyed and bushy-tailed and very annoying long before the humans stop groaning and wincing at loud noises and bright lights.